Semantic colors in an Angular Material component
My Angular Material v18 application allows the user to set their theme but one component group, the "order control", has two semantic colors: blue for "buy"; and red for "sell" (similar to blue for "cold" and red for "hot" in a weather application) which are independent of the theme. Here's an HTML version that kinda does what it should followed by an Angular Material section which does not change color.
How can I get the Angular Material order control to change the semantic colors when BUY/SELL is selected, similarly to the HTML version?
Here's the HTML version:
<div class="order-control">
  <div>
    <span [class]="buyColor()" (click)="isSell=false">BUY</span>
    <span [class]="sellColor()" (click)="isSell=true">SELL</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="units">Units</label>
    <input
      [class]="getColor()"
      type="range"
      id="units"
      name="units"
      [min]="unitsMin"
      [max]="unitsMax"
      [(ngModel)]="units"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <input
      [class]="getColor()"
      type="range"
      id="price"
      name="price"
      [min]="priceMin"
      [max]="priceMax"
      [(ngModel)]="price"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button [class]="getColor()" type="button">Submit order</button>
  </div>
</div>

And here's a similar version with Angular Material but the colors of the toggle, sliders, and submit button should change when selecting the order "side" (i.e., buy or sell):
<div class="order-control">
  <div>
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="side" [(ngModel)]="isSell">
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="false">BUY</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="true">SELL</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="units">Units</label>
    <mat-slider
      [max]="unitsMax"
      [min]="unitsMin"
      [step]="unitsStep"
      discrete showTickMarks>
      <input matSliderThumb [(ngModel)]="units" #unitsSlider />
    </mat-slider>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <mat-slider
      [max]="priceMax"
      [min]="priceMin"
      [step]="priceStep"
      discrete showTickMarks>
      <input matSliderThumb [(ngModel)]="price" #priceSlider />
    </mat-slider>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button mat-flat-button>Submit Order</button>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
.order-control {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  .sell {
    color: red;
    accent-color: red;
  }

  .buy {
    color: blue;
    accent-color: blue;
  }
}

TypeScript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ FormsModule, MatButtonModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatSliderModule ],
  templateUrl: './main.html',
  styleUrl: './main.css',
})
export class App {
  isSell: boolean = false;

  units = 1;
  unitsMin = 1;
  unitsMax = 10;
  unitsStep = 1;

  price = 500;
  priceMin = 0;
  priceMax = 1000;
  priceStep = 25;

  buyColor() {
    return this.isSell ? '' : 'buy';
  }

  sellColor() {
    return this.isSell ? 'sell' : '';
  }

  getColor() {
    return this.isSell ? 'sell' : 'buy';
  }
}

Here's a working sample.

To achieve your desired effect, add the following to your styles.scss file:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$my-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
      primary: mat.$violet-palette
  )
));

html {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
}

$blue-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: mat.$blue-palette
    )
  )
);

$red-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: mat.$red-palette
    )
  )
);

.blue {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($blue-theme);
}

.red {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($red-theme);
}

Then modify your order-control div as follows:
<div class="order-control" [class]="isSell ? 'red' : 'blue'">

Good luck with your project.
Here's a PoC.

Indeed, that works! With your example, I see what you (and Kibe) are suggesting: use the primary colors of the "buy-theme" or "sell-theme" in the "order-component" so no need for anything but the 'primary' palette.

You can try to create a custom theme for the specific components like so
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$custom-palette: (
  50: var(--Your-colors),
  ...
)
 
$custom-primary: mat.define-palette($custom-palette, 500)

$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $custom-primary,
    accent: $custom-accent,
  ),
))


$buy: mat.define-palette($theme, 500)

@include mat-button-theme($buy)

.buy-theme {
  @include mat-button-theme($buy);
}

Then add logic that assign CSS variables here --Your-colors

The challenge with Material 2 is that there are three colors: primary, accent, and warning...and I need two more: buy; and, sell. It looks like Material 3 will have a few more so that might be an option when all the Angular Material components support M3.

As far as I'm aware, all Angular Material components support M3.

With Ch Ryder's more complete example, I see what you (both) are suggesting: use the primary colors of "buy-theme" or "sell-theme" in the "order-component" so we don't need anything but the 'primary' palette. Thank you Kibe and Ch!

I would advise against doing so, since it would break the design : when you implement a design system, there's no "independent component", it should all follow the design provided.
That being said, just apply your class conditionally ?
<mat-button-toggle [value]="true" [class.sell]="isSell">SELL</mat-button-toggle>


Yeah, I hear what you're saying @MGX - the challenge with Material 2 is that there are three colors: primary, accent, and warning...and I need two more: buy; and, sell. It looks like Material 3 will have a few more so that might be an option when all the Angular Material components support M3.

With respect to the conditional class, yeah, that changes the text color like the HTML, but it'd be nicer if the background changes. And the sliders don't seem to change with this type of change.

maybe a more general solution is possible using the @material/material-color-utilities package
once you have established the seed colors for the warm and cold themes use:
generateThemeFromSeed(color: string) {
    

const argb = argbFromHex(color);
const targetElement = document.documentElement;

// Get the theme from a hex color
const theme = themeFromSourceColor(argb);

// Apply theme to root element
applyTheme(theme, {
  target: targetElement,
  dark: true or false
  brightnessSuffix: true,
});

const styles = targetElement.style;

for (const key in styles) {
  if (Object.hasOwn(styles, key)) {
    const propName = styles[key];

    // color utilities generate variables with --md-sys- prefix, we need to change it to --sys
    if (propName.indexOf('--md-sys') === 0) {
      const sysPropName = '--sys' + propName.replace('--md-sys-color', '');
      targetElement.style.setProperty(
        sysPropName,
        targetElement.style.getPropertyValue(propName)
      );
    }
  }
}
}

